# Docker, PHP5.5 - Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, php-5.5

I'm trying to get Docker running in my local development environment using PHP5.5.

I'm getting an error:

```
Call to undefined function mysql_connect()
```

It looks like extensions are not being installed correctly.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM php:5-fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

and my docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  php-apache:
    image: php:5.5-apache
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 8001:80
    links:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
```

Any help appreciated.

Regards,
Stephen

Comment: "Note, there are no error messages" — Perhaps that has something to do with the decision to **suppress error messages** using `@`!!!

Comment: "causing me some issues — What issues?

Comment: "There seems to be a problem" — What problem?

Comment: "causing the issue" — What issue?

Comment: You've listed a bunch of warnings, but not actually said what problem you are having or how the warnings relate to it.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin, I didn't know @ suppressed the errors.

Comment: @Quentin, I'll update post to make clearer.

Comment: I am also getting the same error, Please tell me how to fix this error